# Why am I getting a type name instead of the text from my textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I am making a program here. It's a simple Hotel reservations program. This is how it is structured.

I'm having trouble passing info across forms. For example, I have a total amount qty being called in a new form's textbox and I am getting  this System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: $1,200.00.

So, I'm getting the amount alright but the rest of that garbage as well. :(

My code,

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Gives the first textbox focus
    Me.ActiveControl = CCTypeComboBox
    AmountTextBox.Text = Form2.TotalTextBox.ToString()
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: update the question with the line of code that pulls the amount (and garbage)

Comment: There you go! The box is not big enough to see it but you can see the start of the statement "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: $1,200.00".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bingo! change:

`AmountTextBox.Text = Form2.TotalTextBox.ToString()`

to:

`AmountTextBox.Text = Form2.TotalTextBox.Text`